# iText7 doesn't properly process dashed lines during the SVG image to PDF conversion

Tags: java, pdf, svg, itext, itext7

When I try to convert dashed line svg images to pdf, I am getting straight line over pdf instead of dashed line. I am using itext library (latest version 7.1.15). I am using below code to perform the task. Please provide a solution to exactly get the dashed lines on pdf

```
    private static String svg = "...\\Desktop\\Svg\\image.svg";
    private static String output = "...Desktop\\pdf\\result.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (InputStream svgStream = new FileInputStream(new File(svg));
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(
                        new PdfWriter(output, new WriterProperties().setCompressionLevel(0)))) {

            ISvgProcessorResult result = SvgConverter.process(SvgConverter.parse(svgStream, null), null);
            ISvgNodeRenderer node = result.getRootRenderer();

            PdfFormXObject pdfObj = SvgConverter.convertToXObject(node, pdfDoc);
            Image image = new Image(pdfObj);
            Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.add(image);
            Table table = new Table(1);
            table.addCell(cell);
            doc.add(table);
            doc.close();
        }

    }

}

-----------------------
//below code is used to create svg image (to get svg image create image.svg and paste below code)

<svg version="1.2" baseprofile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewbox="122 0 841.89 595.275" overflow="visible" xml:space="preserve"> 
   <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5669" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="2,2,0,0,0,0" x1="503.822" y1="305.19" x2="530.43" y2="324.436" /> 
  </svg>
```

Comment: Quite likely it's related to your `stroke-dash-array` using rounded linecaps. Try `stroke-dasharray="2 2"`

Comment: Hi @herrstrietzel, Thanks for the approach. I tried by changing the stock-dasharray as you said, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The dashes lines are not supported by iText SVG to PDF converter at the moment. Since iText is open source, you can create a pull request to improve that

Comment: Hi @AlexeySubach, Thanks for informing about this. Let me look into some alternatives.

Comment: @Indmat here is a PR with the initial implementation for the dashed lines - you may want to build the source code from that PR and try again: https://github.com/itext/itext7/pull/97

Comment: Hello @AlexeySubach , above PR provides the expected results on dashed lines. When can we expect this to be delivered to itext library. shall we customize the stroke implementation provided in above PR by extending any itext7 library classes. We are not able to overide AbstractSvgNodeRenderer.preDraw() since its scope is not public or protected. Also, AbstractSvgNodeRenderer.draw() is final so we will not be able to override this. could you please suggest a solution to implement the stroke implementation by using itext7 library

Comment: It would be more appropriate to ask on the plans / ETA to include the changes into the iText library on the PR discussion itself. The more interest you express there, the more priority it will potentially get I assume.

Comment: In terms of the way to use the changes in your code, I would suggest to build the library from the fork (PR) for now and use the custom built binaries in your code